# Is the union of regular languages regular?

Tags: regular-language, proof

If the langages L1,...,Ln are regular, is the union of them regular too?

We know that the union of two regular languages is a regular language. How to prove that the union of many regular languages also is regular?

Comment: Maybe it is a better place for your question: [cstheory.stackexchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? If the union of 2 regular languages is a regular language, then the union of 3 will also be.

Comment: You can prove it by induction.

Comment: If Union(L1, L2, L3) is the same as Union(Union(L1, L2), L3), then you got your answer. But is it? ...( I don't really know what I'm, saying).

Answer (score 5):

You can use induction. Here's a very very rusty sketch of the proof.

**Given -**

Union of two regular languages is regular.

Let f(n) be a function representing the union of n regular languages.

**Question**
Is f(n) a regular language?

**Base Case -**

if n = 1, then the union of a single regular language is regular.

if n = 2, then, by the given hypothesis, we know that f(2) is regular.

**Inductive Hypothesis-**

Assume for all n <= k that f(n) is regular.

**Inductive Step -**

Let n = k+1. We know by the inductive hypothesis that f(k) is a regular language. So . . .

f(n) = f(k+1) = Lk+1 U f(k)

Where Lk+1 is the k+1st regular language. Since f(k) and Lk+1 are regular, then f(n) = f(k+1) is regular by the given hypothesis.

QED

**For More on Inductive Proofs**

Wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Khan Academy - https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/seq_induction/proof_by_induction/v/proof-by-induction